# Graph API Explorer > Get User Access Token > always gives "Token Expired"; What's wrong?! & How to overcome?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A little **Update*** at the end of the question.

---

It is the very first time I try to use Facebook API. I am following this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwbO_PdwK_4). I logged in correctly to Facebook and after that I registered to [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/) I followed these steps:

- Click **Tools & Support**
- Under **Tools** click **Graph API Explorer**
- Select **Graph API Explorer**
- Select **Get User Access Token**
- Select All the options from both **User Data Permissions** & **Extended Permissions**
- Click **Get Access Token** - After that I click three **OKay**'s with default settings.

I got what is shown in this image:
I clicked on *refresh* many times, and I also tried <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but it always gives **Token Expired**.

[image]

---

**Update***

I copied the access token despite the message **"Token Expired"** is still exist, and I continue following the tutorial, and it works OK!!

I am happy that it works now. But what is the wrong that yields this alert message?!

Comment: Maybe a long shot, but is your computer's clock on correct time and date?

Comment: @jehna1 - Yes time and date of computer's clock is correct.

Comment: @jehna1 your comment helped me. Thanks a ton!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Token expired message is due to incorrect system time being set. Simply fix your system time, reload the page and click 'refresh token'. Followed and can verify @jehna1 is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the clock in the taskbar.
Select "Adjust date/time."

Set Time Automatically:
Toggle on "Set time automatically."

Set Time Zone Automatically:
toggle on "Set time zone automatically."

Save Changes:
Click "Change" or "Sync now" to apply the changes.